# Записать даные из значения переменной в файл .txt Builder C++

Tags: c++, c++builder

Как записать даные из значения переменной в файл txt?

```
'     AnsiString t;        
    if (RadioButton1->Checked == true)        {    
    t = t + "text" + " ";              }     
    t->Lines->SaveToFile("1.txt");    '
```

Comment: билдер не билдер разницы нет. Вам нужно создать поток для записи fstream типа так ofstream fout("1.txt"); после чего можно либо так fout<<t; либо так fout.write(t.c_str, t.length()). Только нужно потом файл закрыть

Comment: а вообще по builder  справка http://wladm.narod.ru/Borland/filestxt.html

Comment: можна пожалуйста на примере моего кода показать спасибо?

Comment: а можно больше кода?? этот кусок не информативен